# HTML error causing page refresh in SharePoint

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint, page-refresh

I have written some rudimentary code on a SharePoint page and am having some serious issues that I cannot figure out.  Essentially, the page will have the user fill out a short survey and once submitted, will bring up a number of stacked images using embedded JavaScript.  There is also a reset button which clears all entered information and hides the images.

When a user navigates to the page and completes the survey for the first time, the images will populate but the page will refresh, clearing all of the input information and once again hide the images.  I put in a confirm leaving page code snippet so that the user can stay on the page.  However, if the user resets the page and submits the survey again, it no longer tries to navigate away from the page.  As many times as the user fills out the survey, it will only try to refresh the page on the first attempt.

Using randomly inserted JavaScript alerts, I have found that this refresh (whatever the cause) occurs after the central JavaScript function has finished, so the error must be in the HTML.

Has anyone had this issue before?  If there is an issue with the HTML, I attached the code below:

```
<div id="neodegdiv1" style="position: absolute; z-index: 100; background-color: black;
    height: 88px; width: 257px; margin-left: 4px; margin-top: 117px; visibility: hidden">
</div>
<div id="neodegdiv2" style="position: absolute; z-index: 20; margin-left: 4px; margin-top: 117px;
    visibility: hidden">
    <iframe id="neodegifrm" style="visibility: hidden" height="88" width="257"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="abicurediv1" style="position: absolute; z-index: 100; background-color: black;
    height: 88px; width: 259px; margin-left: 262px; margin-top: 117px; visibility: hidden">
</div>
<div id="abicurediv2" style="position: absolute; z-index: 20; margin-left: 262px;
    margin-top: 117px; visibility: hidden">
    <iframe id="abicureifrm" style="visibility: hidden" height="88" width="259"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="ipidegbdiv1" style="position: absolute; z-index: 100; background-color: black;
    height: 88px; width: 259px; margin-left: 262px; margin-top: 206px; visibility: hidden">
</div>
<div id="ipidegbdiv2" style="position: absolute; z-index: 20; margin-left: 262px;
    margin-top: 206px; visibility: hidden">
    <iframe id="ipidegbifrm" style="visibility: hidden" height="88" width="259"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="ipidegadiv1" style="position: absolute; z-index: 100; background-color: black;
    height: 88px; width: 256px; margin-left: 522px; margin-top: 117px; visibility: hidden">
</div>
<div id="ipidegadiv2" style="position: absolute; z-index: 20; margin-left: 522px;
    margin-top: 117px; visibility: hidden">
    <iframe id="ipidegaifrm" style="visibility: hidden" height="88" width="256"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="noncasdashboarddiv" style="position: absolute; z-index: 10; margin-left: 0px;
    visibility: hidden">
    <embed id="noncasdashboardifrm" target="_top" style="visibility: hidden" src="" height="300"
        width="800" scrolling="no" />
</div>
<div id="dashboarddiv" style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; margin-left: 0px; visibility: hidden">
    <embed id="dashboardifrm" target="_top" style="visibility: hidden" src="" height="600"
        width="800" scrolling="no" />
</div>
<div id="spartandiv1" style="position: absolute; z-index: 100; background-color: black;
    height: 69px; width: 128px; margin-left: 133px; margin-top: 143px; visibility: hidden">
</div>
<div id="spartandiv2" style="position: absolute; z-index: 20; margin-left: 133px;
    margin-top: 143px; visibility: hidden">
    <iframe id="spartanifrm" style="visibility: hidden" height="69" width="128"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="steapdiv1" style="position: absolute; z-index: 100; background-color: black;
    height: 69px; width: 255px; margin-left: 522px; margin-top: 143px; visibility: hidden">
</div>
<div id="steapdiv2" style="position: absolute; z-index: 20; margin-left: 522px; margin-top: 143px;
    visibility: hidden">
    <iframe id="steapifrm" style="visibility: hidden" height="69" width="255"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="alliancediv1" style="position: absolute; z-index: 100; background-color: black;
    height: 69px; width: 259px; margin-left: 263px; margin-top: 143px; visibility: hidden">
</div>
<div id="alliancediv2" style="position: absolute; z-index: 20; margin-left: 263px;
    margin-top: 143px; visibility: hidden">
    <iframe id="allianceifrm" style="visibility: hidden" height="69" width="259"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="ipiabidiv1" style="position: absolute; z-index: 100; background-color: black;
    height: 69px; width: 387px; margin-left: 263px; margin-top: 212px; visibility: hidden">
</div>
<div id="ipiabidiv2" style="position: absolute; z-index: 20; margin-left: 263px;
    margin-top: 212px; visibility: hidden">
    <iframe id="ipiabiifrm" style="visibility: hidden" height="69" width="387"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="arnraddiv1" style="position: absolute; z-index: 100; background-color: black;
    height: 69px; width: 127px; margin-left: 650px; margin-top: 212px; visibility: hidden">
</div>
<div id="arnraddiv2" style="position: absolute; z-index: 20; margin-left: 650px;
    margin-top: 212px; visibility: hidden">
    <iframe id="arnradifrm" style="visibility: hidden" height="69" width="127"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="abicabdiv1" style="position: absolute; z-index: 100; background-color: black;
    height: 59px; width: 387px; margin-left: 263px; margin-top: 281px; visibility: hidden">
</div>
<div id="abicabdiv2" style="position: absolute; z-index: 20; margin-left: 263px;
    margin-top: 281px; visibility: hidden">
    <iframe id="abicabifrm" style="visibility: hidden" height="59" width="387"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="tcelldiv1" style="position: absolute; z-index: 100; background-color: black;
    height: 57px; width: 514px; margin-left: 263px; margin-top: 340px; visibility: hidden">
</div>
<div id="tcelldiv2" style="position: absolute; z-index: 20; margin-left: 263px; margin-top: 340px;
    visibility: hidden">
    <iframe id="tcellifrm" style="visibility: hidden" height="57" width="514"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="enzaseizdiv1" style="position: absolute; z-index: 100; background-color: black;
    height: 69px; width: 259px; margin-left: 263px; margin-top: 397px; visibility: hidden">
</div>
<div id="enzaseizdiv2" style="position: absolute; z-index: 20; margin-left: 263px;
    margin-top: 397px; visibility: hidden">
    <iframe id="enzaseizifrm" style="visibility: hidden" height="69" width="259"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="mln0128div1" style="position: absolute; z-index: 100; background-color: black;
    height: 69px; width: 255px; margin-left: 522px; margin-top: 397px; visibility: hidden">
</div>
<div id="mln0128div2" style="position: absolute; z-index: 20; margin-left: 522px;
    margin-top: 397px; visibility: hidden">
    <iframe id="mln0128ifrm" style="visibility: hidden" height="69" width="255"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="mln8237div1" style="position: absolute; z-index: 100; background-color: black;
    height: 39px; width: 514px; margin-left: 263px; margin-top: 465px; visibility: hidden">
</div>
<div id="mln8237div2" style="position: absolute; z-index: 20; margin-left: 263px;
    margin-top: 465px; visibility: hidden">
    <iframe id="mln8237ifrm" style="visibility: hidden" height="39" width="514"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="bayerdiv1" style="position: absolute; z-index: 100; background-color: black;
    height: 39px; width: 514px; margin-left: 263px; margin-top: 504px; visibility: hidden">
</div>
<div id="bayerdiv2" style="position: absolute; z-index: 20; margin-left: 263px; margin-top: 504px;
    visibility: hidden">
    <iframe id="bayerifrm" style="visibility: hidden" height="39" width="514"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="il10div1" style="position: absolute; z-index: 100; background-color: black;
    height: 50px; width: 255px; margin-left: 522px; margin-top: 542px; visibility: hidden">
</div>
<div id="il10div2" style="position: absolute; z-index: 20; margin-left: 522px; margin-top: 542px;
    visibility: hidden">
    <iframe id="il10ifrm" style="visibility: hidden" height="50" width="255"></iframe>
</div>
<h3>Metastatic/Non-Metastatic</h3>
<input type="radio" id="metyes" name="Met/NoMet" />Metastatic<br />
<input type="radio" id="metno" name="Met/NoMet" />Non-Metastatic <br />
<p></p>
<hr>
<h3>Castration Resistant/Sensitive</h3>
<input type="radio" id="casyes" name="Castration" />Castration Resistant<br />
<input type="radio" id="casno" name="Castration" />Castration Sensitive<br />
<p></p>
<hr>
<h3>Prior Chemotherapy</h3>
<input type="radio" id="chemoyes" name="Chemo" />Yes<br />
<input type="radio" id="chemono" name="Chemo" />No<br />
<p></p>
<hr>
<h3>Prior Abiraterone</h3>
<input type="radio" id="abiyes" name="Abi" />Yes<br />
<input type="radio" id="abino" name="Abi" />No<br />
<p></p>
<hr>
<h3>Prior Enzalutamide</h3>
<input type="radio" id="enzayes" name="Enza" />Yes<br />
<input type="radio" id="enzano" name="Enza" />No<br />
<p></p>
<hr>
<h3>Previous Protocols</h3>
<input type="checkbox" id="neodeg" style="align: left" name="prevprotocol">11-182
Neo-Degarelix<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="abicure" style="align: left" name="prevprotocol">12-187
AbiCure<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="ipidega" style="align: left" name="prevprotocol">13-134
Ipi-Degarelix (Cohort A)<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="ipidegb" style="align: left" name="prevprotocol">13-134
Ipi-Degarelix (Cohort B)<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="spartan" style="align: left" name="prevprotocol">13-243
SPARTAN<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="alliance" style="align: left" name="prevprotocol">13-247
Alliance<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="ipiabi" style="align: right" name="prevprotocol">12-120
Ipi + Abi<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="abicabazi" style="align: left" name="prevprotocol">14-046
Abi +/- Cabazi<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="enzaseizure" style="align: right" name="prevprotocol">13-231
Enza Seizure<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="mln0128" style="align: left" name="prevprotocol">13-143
MLN0128<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="tcell" style="align: right" name="prevprotocol">09-036
T-Cell<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="arnrad" style="align: left" name="prevprotocol">13-025
ARN-RAD 001<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="steap" style="align: right" name="prevprotocol">11-016
STEAP<br />
<p></p>
<hr>
<input type="submit" onclick="pullAnswers2()" style="background-color: green">
<input type="RESET" onclick="return clearAll()" style="background-color: red">
<!--<INPUT type=reset onClick="hideDashboard()" style="background-color:yellow" value="Hide">-->
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your submit button is the problem.  You call the javascript function `pullAnswers2()` when the user clicks the button, but it doesn't prevent the button from completing the submit process.  Easiest way to fix this is

```
<input type="submit" onclick="pullAnswers2();return false" style="background-color: green">
```